# Does Android emulator need internet connection to launch?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, android-emulator

I have installed VSCODE and Flutter, dart and some Android emulators on Windows 10, but noticed that it seems Android emulators need internet connection to launch and when I disconnect internet connection they do not work properly. I get this error message for example at this time:

```
ailed to launch Nexus_5x: Error: Emulator didn't connect within 60 seconds
```

Last night it was OK but today I get this error message!

I also noticed that it seems Android emulators consume a lot of internet traffic and they are downloading something everyday, but I don't know what/why?

I want to know if I am true, how can I restrict their internet usage?
Is it possible to use VSCODE/emulator for Flutter coding without having internet connection?

Answer (score 1):

Create an android virtual device from your Android studio but make sure you have good RAM size and CPU. Open Android Studio > Configure > AVD Manager then create virtual device. It only needs internet connection when creating AVD.

Answer (score 0):

In General a Project Will Need internet connection for the first time in App Creation  .